# Breaking Link with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, url, explode

I want to break down this URL into variables.

```
http://example.com/user.php?u=38456
```

I want the value after `u=`; for example, `38456` or `36491` or some other humeric value.

When I get that value I will put that here:

```
$url = /* that value */;

function gameStats($url)
{
    $result = file_get_contents('http://www.popre.net/game.php?u='.$url.'');
    $expl = explode('"',$result);
    print_r($expl);
}
gameStats($url);
```

If I put the URL value in there, it will give me arrays that I will use to show game reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str). Something like this should work:

```
$url = 'http://popre.net/user.php?u=38456';
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);
echo $params['u']; // Outputs 38456
```

You can see it working in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/I1tsTK).

To get it in the function, pass it as a parameter and concatenate it within the string:

```
function gameStats( $u)
{
    $result = file_get_contents('http://popre.net/game.php?u="' . $u . '"');
    $expl = explode('"',$result);
    print_r($expl);
}
gameStats( 38456); // Or gameStats( $params['u']);
```

Comment: But how to put it here:


function games()
{


$result = file_get_contents('http://popre.net/game.php?u="PUT HERE"');
$expl = explode('"',$result);

print_r($expl);
  
}
games();

Comment: @Waleed I updated my answer. If it still does not answer your question, you are not explaining your problem clear enough.

Comment: @Waleed - You're welcome! If my post answered your question, the best thanks you can give is to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I accepted it, I wish I could vote it up!
May be in future Questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Can get with `$_GET`:

```
$url = isset($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)